# angularjs directive cannot get attributes ending with "-start"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wanted to use `on-drag-start` as an attribute in AngularJS directive, called `ngDraggable`.
However, it seems not possible to have that attribute.

The following code is in pure javascript, and I can get `on-drag-start` as an attribute.
I think I can get any attribute regardless of attribute name.

```
<h1 id="tag1" on-drag-start="START" on-drag="DRAG" on-drag-end="END" >Hello Plunker!</h1>
```

Attributes in pure javasctipt DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/6iODSnf56KtwPFpoC7ck?p=preview

However, in the following code in AngularjS, I cannot get `onDragStart` as an attribute, but it is possible to get `onDragBegin` as an attribute.

```
<h1 id="tag1" ng-draggable  on-drag="DRAG" on-drag-end="END"
  on-drag-start="START" on-drag-begin="BEGIN">Hello Plunker!</h1>
```

Attributes in AngularJS directive DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/RxABAHHlxQJSSZz91CYW?p=preview

Of course, I can change my attribute name from `on-drag-start` to `on-drag-begin`, but I am curious.

My questions are;

1. why I cannot use `on-drag-start` as an attribute name?
2. what's the reason behind it?
3. and, is there any general rule for attribute names?

NOTE: I feel my question is not well formatted. Rewriting is welcomed.

Comment: Here's the github issue on this (that resulted from adding [support multi-element directive](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/e46100f7097d9a8f174bdb9e15d4c6098395c3f2)): [1.2 broke attributes ending with "start" or "end"](https://github.com/wzr1337/angular-gestures/issues/6)

Comment: I had the same issue and wasted a lot of time to figure it out. As far as I have read it is intentional (they mentioned it in a release note) and not recognized as a bug. In my opinion it's a very bad design decision though. They shouldn't have choosen such a common term as suffix.

Comment: I came across the same issue, not being able to use the suffix end or start. However, the only fix I know is using hmDragstart instead of hmDragStart. (http://github.com/wzr1337/angular-gestures)

Answer (score 6):

[This was broken in 1.2](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/e46100f7097d9a8f174bdb9e15d4c6098395c3f2). It's best to rename the attributes to something else and move on.

Comment: Yes, i m moving on by renaming it. As question says, renaming works.  I am just curious if this is bug or this is intentional. Your link says that's for directive, however my usage is  not for a directive but for attribute. It seems like a bug, but AngularJS team's intention might be to reserve all "-end" suffix.

Comment: Crazy; it seems like `-start` would be useful for lots of directives. Thanks for pointing this out. Is this limitation noted anywhere else in the AngularJS documentation for directives? If not, sure seems like it should be!

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this exact thing today and I wasted an hour or so trying to figure out what was wrong with my directive. I am implementing a touch event directive and I named it `dac-touch-start`, and was baffled why it did not fire. Eventually I figured out that the word "start" was to blame.

Looking through the Angular source, it seems there is a special provision for the words "start" and "end" in directive names.

This is the function that links the directives in your templates to the directive definition.

```
/**
 * Looks for directives on the given node and adds them to the directive collection which is
 * sorted.
 *
 * @param node Node to search.
 * @param directives An array to which the directives are added to. This array is sorted before
 *        the function returns.
 * @param attrs The shared attrs object which is used to populate the normalized attributes.
 * @param {number=} maxPriority Max directive priority.
 */
function collectDirectives(node, directives, attrs, maxPriority, ignoreDirective) {

...

var directiveNName = ngAttrName.replace(/(Start|End)$/, '');
if (ngAttrName === directiveNName + 'Start') {
    attrStartName = name;
    attrEndName = name.substr(0, name.length - 5) + 'end';
    name = name.substr(0, name.length - 6);
}
```

This appears to be so that directives such as `ng-repeat-start` ... `ng-repeat-end` can be supported.

As @mmattax suggests, the thing to do is to just name it something else.

Comment: this MUST be documented with red-bold characters, i think

Answer (score 0):

So, *coughcough* it appears that appending a frivolous (additional) -start is a workaround.

i.e. `on-drag-start-start="onStartCallback()"`.

results in an attribute of on-drag-start in the markup,
and it appears to work, on angular 1.2.10.

Your mileage may vary, and I haven't checked for any other misbehavior.