# Using attribute containing 'start' in a directive doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I was trying to pass variables to a directive but I kept on running into issues with one of them constantly returning an 'undefined' value, even after reordering. It seems at first as though Angular doesn't like the word 'start' being used within an attribute name.

**Has anyone come across this before?**

*Note: In the example below, I am creating a slider that requires 4 values passed*

**slider.html**

```
<div ab-range-slider slider-start="10000" slider-step="1000" slider-min="10000" slider-max="100000" >
    <div class="slider"></div>
</div>
```

**slider.js**

```
exports
    .directive('abRangeSlider', function () {

        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                sliderStart: '@',
                sliderStep: '@',
                sliderMin: '@',
                sliderMax: '@'
            },
            controller: function($scope, $element) {

                console.log($scope.sliderStart); // returns undefined
                console.log($scope.sliderStep);  // returns 1000
                console.log($scope.sliderMin);   // returns 1000
                console.log($scope.sliderMax);   // returns 100000

                // rest of code here

            }
        };
    });
```

Things to note:

1. Even if I change the variable order, the same thing occurs.
2. If I change the variable name to 'slider-strt' it works.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242444/angularjs-directive-cannot-get-attributes-ending-with-start

Comment: Great, couldn't find anything on initial searches but this explains it all. Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above in the answer by @miqid, this was introduced by design in [1.2](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/e46100f7097d9a8f174bdb9e15d4c6098395c3f2)