# Directive not getting attributes correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive that wraps jQuery FullCalendar plugin.

This is how I use the directive

```
<div sg-calendar
         format-column-header-month='dddd'
         format-column-header-week='ddd/dd'
         format-column-header-day='dddd/dd'
         format-calendar-header-month='MMM, yyyy'
         format-calendar-header-day='MMM dd, yyyy'
         format-calendar-header-week-start='MMM dd'
         format-calendar-header-week-end='-MMM dd, yyyy'
         event-endpoint='REST/CalendarActivity'
         event-fetch-endpoint='someRestUrl'
         app-init-url='someRestUrl'
         service-data-mintime='minTime'
         service-data-maxtime='maxTime'
         default-view='agendaDay'
         width='100%'>
    </div>
```

this is my scope definition in the directive

```
scope: {
  // Configures the header in month mode.
  formatColumnHeaderMonth: '@',
  // Configures the header in week mode.
  formatColumnHeaderWeek: '@',
  // Configures the header in day mode.
  formatColumnHeaderDay: '@',
  // Configures the calendar header in month mode.                    
  formatCalendarHeaderMonth: '@',
  // Configures the calendar header in day mode
  formatCalendarHeaderDay: '@',
  // Configures the calendar header for start of week mode
  formatCalendarHeaderWeekStart: '@',
  // Configures the calendar header for end of week mode
  formatCalendarHeaderWeekEnd: '@',
  appInitUrl: '@',
  eventEndpoint: '@',
  eventFetchEndpoint: '@',
  serviceDataMintime: '@',
  serviceDataMaxtime: '@',
  width: '@',
  defaultView: '@',
  height: '@'
},
```

and this is my attrs object on devTools

[image]

The reason I highlighted that property is because in my scope definition and usage I have

```
 format-calendar-header-week-start='MMM dd'
```

and

```
formatCalendarHeaderWeekStart: '@',
```

however, you can see in attrs the property name is

```
formatCalendarHeaderWeek:"MMM dd"
```

You can notice it is missing the *Start* word at the end.

If I do

`scope.formatCalendarHeaderWeek` or `scope.formatCalendarHeaderWeekStart` I get undefined in both cases. The rest of the attributes are working fine.

Is there any limit about naming attributes or any length restriction ?
Why the last part of my attribute name is missing ?

I searched for `formatCalendarHeaderWeek` and `formatCalendarHeaderWeekStart` and they aren't used in any other place.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242444/angularjs-directive-cannot-get-attributes-ending-with-start) in another SO question. (I guess it is duplicated, right?)

> [This was broken in 1.2.](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/e46100f7097d9a8f174bdb9e15d4c6098395c3f2) It's best to rename the attributes to
>   something else and move on.